# Can't access Slim REST API

Tags: .htaccess, slim

In my local environment my project run very well, but when I put in server Slim shows me next error:

> 404 The requested URL /innova-movil/www/api/v1/orderdetail/ordersdetails was not found on this server

Slim REST endpoint:

```
http://138.117.47.13/innova-movil/www/api/v1/orderdetail/ordersdetails
```

In my File .htaccess is like this:

```bash
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

I try changed this and get the same error.

```bash
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ api/v1/orderdetail/ordersdetails/index.php [QSA,L]
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please *never* use capital letters in titles, unless they are required.

Comment: Regarding your question, is your Slim `index.php` file in the `www` directory? And is your `.htaccess` in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, they are. My app is in  http://138.117.47.13/www, my slim api http://138.117.47.13/innova-movil/www/api/v1/orderdetail

Comment: Have you tried the .htaccess from documentation?

http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/web-servers.html

Comment: Hmm, this setup doesn't look right to me at all. If you have an API app in a subdirectory, then your `.htaccess` file should be in *that* subdirectory with a `RewriteBase` set to the relative path of that subdirectory. What is `ordersdetails/index.php`? Is that the Slim index file and, if so, why do you state that the Slim app is in `api/v1/orderdetail` and not `api/v1/orderdetail/orderdetails`?

Comment: I solve just editing  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf  `<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>`  then a exucute in the terminal > a2enmod rewrite